# How to find the parent ID to use when using git cherry-pick -m (cherry picking a pull request)?

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

TL;DR

I need to find the parent ID so I can cherry pick the pull request to another branch (not master).

---

Long version

Several developers (example: coder1 and coder2) have forked dev branch and changed some files. They were finished and have created pull requests to be merge into our dev branch. I have approved all of them.

I want to cherry pick the changes included in the pull request created by coder1 only so I tried this:

```
 git cherry-pick my-hash-id-here
 error: commit my-hash-id-here is a merge but no -m option was given.
 fatal: cherry-pick failed
```

my-hash-id is the hash ID for the pull requests (at least looking at repo)

Any ideas on how to find the parent ID to use?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

First, use `git show` on the commit you want to cherry-pick, and find a line such as this:

```
Merge: abc123 def456
```

The order in which the commits appear determines the number. Here, `abc123` would be parent ID 1 and `def456` would be parent ID 2.

Comment: can you please explain what is "1" and "2"? Thanks again

Comment: 1 and 2 are the "Parent ID's" that you were asking about.

Comment: 1 and 2 are the `<parent-number>` provided to the `-m` option, as referred to in the man page or `git help cherry-pick`: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick